Looking for a slipstream historical fiction childrens novel
I remember as a child I read a historical fiction children's novel set in the late 1700s (the American Revolutionary War.) It was basically historical fiction but the main character was very interested in the future and the natural world and in the book and speculated on something that was not technologically possible at the time and may indeed still be not possible. I am interested in finding it as I love futurism and this is one of the only this-early-in-history examples I can remember

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this book actually science fictional, or just historical fiction with some imaginings of a future possibilities mixed in?  You've tagged this "alternate-history;" what was different about the world of the book?

The latter; and I added alternative history by accident

This is borderline, but I think that imagining technology ahead of the time of the plot just about counts as SF.  I mean, I count the Sherlock Holmes movies where Moriarty's henchman invented radio several years before Marconi as SF.  And that other Sherlock Holmes movie with a submarine disguised as the Loch Ness Monster.

You said the book was set in the 1700s.  But when was it written (or at any rate approximately what year did you read it?)  Was the protagonist an adult or a child? What was the speculative "something" - gadget? trasportation? communication? computation?  energy sources?
